# Does Delta give SkyMiles credit for Aero Mexico flights to Cuba?

Tags: loyalty-programs, cuba, delta-air-lines, aeromexico

I've claimed a few flights with Delta.  All seem to have gone through easily, except for a TIJ-MEX-HAV flight.  I emailed them the details separately, and they said they've put them through manually.

After a few days, both show up (business) and the TIJ-MEX leg has points credited, but not the MEX-HAV leg.  Is this a America-Cuba relations thing, or just a Delta mistake?

(I know I can email them and ask, but I like to know what I'm talking about before I contact them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look through Delta's SkyMiles partner rules for Aeromexico, they state that flights to/from Havana do not earn miles.

http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/skymiles/earn-miles/earn-miles-with-partners/airlines/aeromexico.html

No idea why, but likely due to US trade restrictions against Cuba.

Comment: Ah, well found.  That's kinda crummy, but ah well. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMayo With the recent restoration of diplomatic relations between the US and Cuba, that part of Delta's agreement with Aeromexico may well be renegotiated in the next few months, but it's probably not a high priority for Delta, who if anything are likely to be working on their own service to Cuba.

Comment: @choster sadly that doesn't help get me my points from June (sob) ;)